# Photoshop canvas size inaccurate to mm input sizes

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Just recently when I go to create a new Photoshop (CC2014) document, I put in the document size (e.g. 220 x 158.5mm) but when I open up the canvas size panel the dimensions are different (i.e. 219.96 x 158.5mm). I'm thinking it might be a simple setting but can't seem to find anything. When I change the resolution to pixels/cm instead of pixels/inch it works fine, but I am wanting to use PPI.

Answer (score 5):

The size of a document has to be in full pixel increments. That is you can not have half, quarter or 1/π sized pixels. This thus limits the actual sizes you can get.

For example if you want to use 300 dpi to make a 6cm wide document the  closest you can get is:

709 pixels wide  that is 6.002866... cm wide,

next possible increment is,

708 pixels that is 5.9944 cm wide.

Thus, you can not have a 6 cm wide document at 300 dpi. You can have something close, but not exact.